# Excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I was hoping someone can help me with a formula.

What I am trying to do is format a number as currency if the column 3 to its left contains a specific text.

For example,

```
Col1, Col2, Col3
YES   a     5$
NO    b     4
YES   c     3$
```

In this case 5 and 4 are formatted as currency since their corresponding Col1 is YES.

Comment: use the formula `=$A1="YES"` and apply it to column C.

Comment: OK It worked but I added in as a conditional format. They all reference the same cell. So if the first row matches the condition then whole table gets formatted else none of them gets formatted. How do I make it so each row references its rows coll

Comment: Then you did not use the formula as I stated.  the row must be relative not absolute.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=$A1="YES"
```

As the formula and apply it to Column C

[image]

Comment: What I did was I used the formula =$W$2="YES". I applied this to the whole column. But what happens is if $W$2 is YES then all of col c gets formatted.

Comment: Maybe its because the table is already created so it doesn't auto increment?

Comment: As stated the row must be relative: `=$W2="YES"`